# a href tag getting 0 height inspite of the attribute being declared

Tags: css, height, width, href

All,

On my website [www.coutallure.com](http://www.coutallure.com)

There is a 'forgot password' div thats sitting right underneath the 'password' field at the bottom of the page.

Now, even though, I have specified the height & width of the div (id: fpass), the 'a href' tag inside this div doesnt inherit the height from the parent div (fpass).

I have specified the height & width of the 'a href' tag as well and as per the firebug, the height & width is being taken into consideration by the browser, however still, the height of the 'a href' tag remains zero!

Can anyone please enlighten me why this is the way it is, i.e. the height & width of the 'a href' tag is not the actual height & width being used by the browser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `a` element is inline by default, add `display: block` to make it listen to its dimensions.

An inline element won't listen to its dimensions set with CSS.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/FLAdM/).

Comment: +1 Good eye. Didn't realize the anchor had a background image and was meant to be empty :)

Comment: Thank you Alex for giving me an easy lesson to remember. Problem solved.